# How to access dynamicly created objects in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamic

I have created a dynamic table and I want to access one of the created objects in a javascript. For example: How do I adress a dynamicly created button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myJavaScriptFunction()
{ 
 //How do I know here which button triggered the function?
}
</script>

<table>
<% for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { %> 
  <tr class="rowcell">
   <td class="datacell">
   <input type="button" id='<%="button-no-"+i%>' value="myButton" onclick="myJavaScriptFunction()"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance
/John

Comment: Do you want to access this dynamically created content in Javascript or ASP?

Comment: how are you creating dynamic controls?in codebehind?or in javascript?

Comment: I want to access the dynamically created content in Javascript.

Comment: The dynamic controls are created in codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map out the parameter to be the object:

```
function myJavaScriptFunction(object)
{ 
 //How do I know here which button triggered the function?
    var id = object.id;
}
```

In your HTML, you'll need to do:

```
onclick="myJavaScriptFunction(this)"
```

This is the point where you call the function, and you pass in the `this` keyword as an argument.

The keyword `this` refers to whichever HTML element did the calling, which is whatever button you clicked. The object has the attribute `id` which you have defined in the function as `object.id`. The value of attribute `id` is basically the "id" field of the input tag.

Putting it all together, you get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myJavaScriptFunction(object) // You're defining the function as having a parameter that it accepts. In this case, it accepts an object.
{ 
   alert(object.id); // Alert the object's id.
   // Do what you want with object.id
}
</script>

<table>
<% for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { %> 
  <tr class="rowcell">
   <td class="datacell">
   <input type="button" id='<%="button-no-"+i%>' value="myButton" onclick="myJavaScriptFunction(this)"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the button element as a parameter to the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myJavaScriptFunction(button)
{ 
 //button triggered the function
}
</script>

<table>
<% for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { %> 
  <tr class="rowcell">
   <td class="datacell">
   <input type="button" id='<%="button-no-"+i%>' value="myButton" onclick="myJavaScriptFunction(this)"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myJavaScriptFunction(button)
{ 
   alert($(button).attr('id')); // gets the id of the button that called the function
}
</script>

<table>
<% for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { %> 
  <tr class="rowcell">
   <td class="datacell">
   <input type="button" id='<%="button-no-"+i%>' value="myButton" onclick="myJavaScriptFunction(this)"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, like this

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button-no-1");
```

Comment: Yes, and you'd hard-code all the possible dynamic buttons in advance, right?

Comment: @walther, you clearly missed the point, which was to show how you would do it, not provide a full solution.

Comment: @JustinHarvey, not saying you must give it on a silver plate, but maybe show a basic idea. Your example doesn't show anything, except the most basic static element retrieval, which is utterly useless in this scenario. John needs a way to get an element, which has an unknown ID, because it was created dynamically. You show him how to find a static element instead. Understand the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as follows:

```
<input type="button" id='<%="button-no-"+i%>' value="myButton" onclick="myJavaScriptFunction('<%="button-no-"+i%>')"/>



<script type="text/javascript">
function myJavaScriptFunction(buttonId)
{ 
 //How do I know here which button triggered the function?
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know button id:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button-no-1");
```

Comment: Yes, and you'd hard-code all the possible dynamic buttons in advance, right?